# Pass variable to link in loading view to div

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

May be the title is not corresponding to my following explanation.
What I really mean is :

I store an input value in a jquery variable :

```
var id=$("#id-doc").val();
```

I have a div that is loading every second :

```
setInterval(function(){
$('#new_message1_doc').load("<?php echo base_url("medico/newMessageDoc")?>").fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000);
```

How can pass the **variable id** in the url to use it in controller function **newMessageDoc** ?

```
 function newMessageDoc()
 {
 echo $id;
 }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the javascript you take the id just inside the setInterval function, and you add it as a query param in the URL:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var id=$("#id-doc").val();
    $('#new_message1_doc').load("<?php echo base_url("medico/newMessageDoc")?>?id=" + id).fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000);
```

In the codeigniter code, you can get it using the [input class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html):

```
 function newMessageDoc()
 {
     $id = $this->input->get('id');
     echo $id;
 }
```